# Getting the value of <select> without submitting and refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I'm testing this and I could not make it work.
Because I'm doing a cart where I list the products purchased and I have to change the amount of each product with a drop-down list (`<select>`) and immediately update the price.
Please, help me.
Thanks and best regards.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <select id="qty" name="select" onChange="select()">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function select() {
        var selected = $('#qty').val();
        $.ajax({
       url: "tt.php",
       type: "POST",//Based on your requirement you can set it to GET/PUT etc
       data: {
          paramName: $("select").val();//this will get the selected value from the dropdown
       },
       sucess: function(){
         alert("Data submitted");
       }
    });
    }
    </script>
    <?php 
    include 'tt.php';
(It contains $value=$_POST['select'];
echo $value;)

    ?>
```

Comment: use `$("#qty").val();`.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan He already has that in the code.

Comment: `data: $.param($('select')),` PHP side: **name** will be the select name and **value** will be it's value. so you would get `$_POST['selectName'] = 'selectedValue'`. Also, it hurts my head to see a `<select>` named `name="select"`. just use the same name as your `id`

Comment: What exactly is the problem, so what isn't working. Is your ajax not returning the data?

Comment: As you said, Ajax is not returning the value and I could not use it by post and it is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Plain javascript solution, open network tab and check outgoing request

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <select id="qty" name="select">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.querySelector('#qty');
    select.onchange = function(event){
        console.log(event); //proof that it makes http request on change
        var value = event.target.value;
        $.ajax({
           url: "tt.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: {
               paramName: value
          }
        }).done(function() {
           alert( "success" );
        }).fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        });
    }
    </script>
    <?php 
       include 'tt.php';
       (It contains $value=$_POST['select']; //im not php fan, but i guess this should be "paramName", not sure!
       echo $value;)
    ?>
```

Two things happening here
You subscribe to select change event, and pass POST data with "paramName" property,
But your server code expects FORM Data, with select property.

Comment: If I change .done(function() {
           alert( "success" ); to .done(function() {
           alert(value); I could see the value in the alert popup but it is not being sent by POST.

Comment: How do you know was not POST? Have you actually looked at chrome-network-tab? Or you're just saying it because your server endpoint was not hit, those are 2 different things, i don't know php, but i guess `$value=$_POST['select'];` must be `$value=$_POST['paramName'];` instead. The thing is that you wanted request on select:change, now you have another problem which is not this questions idea, so ask another

Answer (score 0):

Change `onChange="select()"` 
to 
`onChange="select(this.value)"` and declare your `select()` function like this `select(selected)` so you can delete `var selected = $('#qty').val();` and then change `paramName: $("select").val();`
to

```
paramName: selected
```

also, aren't you calling the 'select' variable in the post array?
change `paramName:selected` to:

```
select:selected
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work. The php include I made should work?

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove a semicolon after selected. It may be because you have ended the statement there

Comment: Changed the answer again, I think I found your problem. It seems the tt.php page expects the key in the data array to be 'select'